# Como retornar o valor de uma consulta ao banco de dados em outro arquivo javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em que preciso fazer uma consulta a um banco de dados e devolver o valor de retorno para outro arquivo javascript, só que por algum motivo não está exportando nada para o outro arquivo ao fazer `exports.result = resultado;` , segue o código abaixo:

```
//Conexao com BD MySQL
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'database'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

connection.query('SELECT * from informacoes;', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        var resultado = rows;
        exports.result = resultado;
    } else {
        console.log('Erro ao realizar a consulta');
    }
});
```

Comment: qual o erro? você não colocou na sua pergunta

Comment: Editei a pergunta... Quando verifico no arquivo em que deveria exportar, está vazio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível atribuir valores pra variável `exports` de forma assíncrona, que é o  que você está tentando fazer. Você precisa que o valor que você quer exportar seja obtido sincronicamente.

Como a maioria das operações que se faz em um db são feitas por funções assíncronas, não existe uma maneira de exportar nada que resulte dessas operações através do `exports` do js.

O que você pode fazer é exportar uma função que aceita um callback como argumento e executar a sua consulta dentro dessas função. Como por exemplo:

```
//Conexao com BD MySQL
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'database'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

exports.query = function (cb) {
    connection.query('SELECT * from informacoes;', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            var resultado = rows;
            cb(null, resultado);
        } else {
            console.log('Erro ao realizar a consulta');
            cb(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Outra forma seria usar uma IIFE (Imediately Invoked Function Expression) junto com async, mas isso só vai funcionar com ES7 em diante. Outro detalhe é que o driver do mysql que você está usando não trabalha com Promises, então você teria que criar uma função que encapsulasse a query e retornasse uma promise. Desse jeito seu código ficaria assim:

```
function queryWithPromise (query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err)

            resolve(rows)
        })
    }
}

module.exports = (async function () {
    const resultado = await queryWithPromise('SELECT * from informacoes;')
    return resultado
})()
```

Aí você usa o await quando for importar o arquivo:

```
let informacoes
(async function () {
    informacoes = await require('./caminho/pro/arquivo.js')
})()
```

Comment: Ok, mas como eu poderia obter o valor do retorno em uma variável a partir de outro arquivo JS?

Comment: Dessa forma você já consegue obter o valor. Você só precisa executar a função que foi exportada e passar um callback que vai fazer o que quer que você queira fazer com o valor.

No caso do ES7 você consegue usar uma função imediatamente executada assíncrona. Vou adcionar uma resposta explicando esse método.

Comment: Beleza, acabei conseguindo fazer, muitissimo obrigado! Me salvou muito aqui, vlw